# c# How to write to a ini file

Tags: c#, ini

I would like to know how i should write text to a ini file. The reading of the file is already done. Now i just have to know how to write to the file.

It should look like this when its in the INI file:

`[H83052_md7]`
`Description=H83048 processor mode 7`
`BootFile=kernel_52.md7`
`Extension=a20`

If you would like to see how i read from the file ask me for the source code please because i could not figure out how i should do this.

I write it like this:

```
namespace Flashloader
```

`{
    class Controllerlist : List<Controller>
    {
        public Controllerlist FromIniFile()
        {
            StringList input = new StringList().FromFile("Controllers.ini");`

```
        Controller controller = null;

        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            String line = item.Trim();

            if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
            {
                String name = line.Substring(1, line.Length - 2);

                controller = new Controller(name);
                Add(controller);
            }
            else if (controller != null)
            {
                int index = line.IndexOf('=');
                if (index < 0)
                    continue;

                String key = line.Substring(0, index).Trim();
                String value = line.Substring(index + 1).Trim();

                if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "Description"))
                    controller.Description = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "Bootfile"))
                    controller.Bootfile = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "Extension"))
                    controller.Extension = value;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Controller FindByName(String name)
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
            if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(item.Name, name))
                return item;
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this class:

```
public class IniFile
  {
    public string path;

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
      string key,string val,string filePath);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
      string key,string def, StringBuilder retVal,
      int size,string filePath);

    public IniFile(string INIPath)
    {
      path = INIPath;
    }

    public void IniWriteValue(string Section,string Key,string Value)
    {
      WritePrivateProfileString(Section,Key,Value,this.path);
    }

    public string IniReadValue(string Section,string Key)
    {
      StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
      int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section,Key,"",temp,255, this.path);
      return temp.ToString();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you have the kernel 32 things?

Comment: You can use Windows API functions, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution to write/read INi file. http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/IniFile.aspx

Comment: Is the Kernel 32 the file where you are writing to

Comment: Thanks but why is there in the file a text KERNEL 32 what does it stand for.

Comment: Where do you see it ? only dllimport attribute  has kernel32

Comment: Yes that, where is that for

Comment: That is to access unmanaged API methods